# python print variables of a specific line

Tags: python

I want to print variables from a specific line of a python file.

Consider my file has line:

```
self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" (You clicked the button)" )
```

Output has to be:

```
labelvariable
entryvariable
```

I tried a program :

```
import os
import re
with open('adapt.py', 'r') as my_file:

    for vars in dir():
        for line in my_file:

            if vars.startswith("self.") == 0:
                print vars
```

It prints me no output,please help.Answers will be appreciated!

Comment: My guess is that instead of `if vars.startswith("self.") == 0:`, you want `if line.startswith("self.") == 0:`.

Comment: Is there any leading whitespace on the lines? E.g. are the lines indented as they would commonly be in a Python program?

Comment: You are also assuming that `vars()` would operate on the text file; that is an incorrect assumption. The text file would not be parsed as Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to extract all attributes on `self`, you'd be better of actually parsing the file. The [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) can help here.

Subclass the [`ast.NodeVisitor` utility class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) to look for `ast.Attribute` nodes, and test for a `self` name on the `value` side of these:

```
class SelfAttributesVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def __init__(self):
        self.attributes = []

    def visit_Attribute(self, node):
        if isinstance(node.value, ast.Name) and node.value.id == 'self':
            self.attributes.append(node.attr)
        else:
            self.visit(node.value)
```

then pass in the result of [`ast.parse()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.parse) to that:

```
with open('adapt.py', 'r') as my_file:
    source = my_file.read()
    ast_tree = ast.parse(source, 'adapt.py')
    visitor = SelfAttributesVisitor()
    visitor.visit(ast_tree)
    print visitor.attributes
```

Demo on your limited example:

```
>>> import ast
>>> source = 'self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" (You clicked the button)" )'
>>> ast_tree = ast.parse(source, 'adapt.py')
>>> visitor = SelfAttributesVisitor()
>>> visitor.visit(ast_tree)
>>> visitor.attributes
['labelVariable', 'entryVariable']
```

Comment: so,should the class SelfAttributesVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor): must be already provided to the adapt.py before parsing?

Comment: @adarshram: You need to include the class in your code so you can instantiate it.

Comment: @adarshram: You then read `adapt.py`, pass the text to `ast.parse()` and then process the resulting parse tree (abstract syntax tree) with the custom node walker.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to match name by `startswith`, try using some regex to capture groups, representing wanted values. Try using [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) or [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex).

Regex you want will be something like (not tested, written ad-hoc):

`self[.](\w+)[.]set( self.(\w+)[.]get()[+]" (You clicked the button)" )`

Remeber to escape `"` signs. Also, you may want to name those groups, so you can obtain them by name, not by group index.

If you don't know some terms in this context (like groups, regex, capture, etc) - read documentation from links above - it will explain everything.

Comment: how can i print/display it as output?i mean how to use print stmt to display?

Comment: could u modify ur program as  per my question?